# using linux how can I pass the contents of a file as a parameter to an executable?

Tags: linux

let's say I want to run `./program` with a string argument

instead of typing
    `./program string` each time, how can I do `./program <file>` where `<file>` is a file that contains string?

thankyou

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
./program `cat file`
```

If you want the entire file content in a single argument, add double quotation (tested in bash. I think It may vary shell to shell)  :

```
./program "`cat file`"
```

Comment: @HabeebPerwad what is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: @Donentolon,I have written an example as a separate answer to this question. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664783/739331

Answer (score 41):

#### Command

```
./program "$(< file)"
```

#### Explanation

1. `$(cmd)` runs a command and converts its output into a string. `$(cmd)` can also be written with backticks as `` `cmd` ``. I prefer the newer `$(cmd)` as it nests better than the old school backticks.
2. The command we want is `cat file`. And then from the bash man page:

   > The command substitution `$(cat file)` can  be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.
3. The quotes around it make sure that whitespace is preserved, just in case you have spaces or newlines inside of your file. Properly quoting things in shell scripts is a skill that is sorely lacking. Quoting variables and command substitutions is a good habit to good into so you don't get bit later when your file names or variable values have spaces or control characters or other weirdnesses.

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of:

```
./program $(cat file)
./program "$(cat file)"
```

The latter is useful if there may be multiple words in the file and you want them to be treated as a single argument. In any case, I prefer the use if `$()` to backticks simply due to it's ability to nest (which is probably not a *requirement* in this case).

Also keep in mind that this answer (and others) are more related to the shell in use rather than Linux itself. Since the predominant <sup><sup>*and the best :-)*</sup></sup> shell seems to be `bash`, I've coded specifically for that.

This is actually a fairly common way of killing processes under UNIX lookalikes. A daemon (like `cron`) will write its process ID to a file (like `/var/cron.pid`) and you can signal it with something like:

```
kill -HUP $(cat /var/cron.pid)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is xargs:

```
xargs -a file ./program
```

From the man page:

> xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks or newlines, and executes the command one or more times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard input.

In plain speak, xargs will execute the command adding the content of `file` as additional arguments, separating them by spaces or newlines.

See man xargs for more options.

Comment: Even better, drop the cat and use xargs's -a <file> option, which will read items from file instead of standard input.

Comment: "xargs will execute ./program on each line/word that is being piped to it.": this is incorrect. xargs will pass all arguments to the command unless they exceed either the command's allowed limit or a self-defined limit. only in that case it will split the arguments between multiple commands to make sure all of them were used. I will edit it out.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers work but I find the cleanest and easiest to type option is

```
xargs < file ./program
```

Answer (score 1):

This is extension to @robbrit answer.

Consider a *file.txt* with content:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

And the a *program.c* with content:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) 
        printf("Arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]); 
}
```

Here is what happen if you pass command line arguments with quotes and without:

```
$ gcc  program.c -o program

$ ./program `cat file`
Arg 0: ./program
Arg 1: 1
Arg 2: 2
Arg 3: 3
Arg 4: 4
Arg 5: 5
Arg 6: 6

$ ./program "`cat file`"
Arg 0: ./program
Arg 1: 1 2 3
4 5 6
```