# How to run command in cron job with external string

Tags: linux, terminal, cron, centos

I need to run corn job every month to update software license.

The license is ready in text file on remote server (example: http://codebox.ir/soft/license.txt) and update every month.

license.txt content Example "tev3vv5-v343".

I want to grab the license and put in some command:

```
# update xxxx-xxxx
```

how can I make this?

- CentOs 6.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [using linux how can I pass the contents of a file as a parameter to an executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241369/using-linux-how-can-i-pass-the-contents-of-a-file-as-a-parameter-to-an-executabl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a script which fetches the file from your remoteserver

```
wget http://codebox.ir/soft/license.txt
```

Then you get the key out of that textfile and pipe it into your updatecommand

```
update `cat license.txt`
```

note the Backticks, so your script could look like this

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# This script fetches and updates the licensefile
#
wget http://codebox.ir/soft/license.txt;
update `cat license.txt`;
```

make the file executable

```
chmod +x updateLicense.sh
```

and put it in your crontab

```
cd /path/to/script;./updateLicense.sh
```

or to keep it compact, allthough i would check if the file is in an expected format first.

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# This script fetches and updates the licensefile
#

update `wget http://codebox.ir/soft/license.txt`;
```

And with checking if fetch succeeded

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# This script fetches and updates the licensefile
#

URL = http://codebox.ir/soft/license.txt

wget_output=$(wget -q "$URL")
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
update $wget_output
fi
```

No you can develop it further, i'd advise to check the format of the key before updating

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# This script fetches and updates the licensefile
#

# Define URL
URL = http://codebox.ir/soft/license.txt

# Fetch content
wget_output=$(wget -q "$URL")
# Check if fetch suceeded $? is the returnvalue of wget in this case
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   # Use mad Regexskillz to check format of licensekey and update if matched
   if [[ $wget_output == [a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+ ]] ; then update $wget_output; fi
fi
```

I'd also return some values to further raise quality of your script, also i'd pass the url and the regex into the function to keep the script reusable but that's a matter of taste